# python3 numpy averaging across duplicate timestamp values

Tags: python, numpy

I am working with a large ordered list(100k+, ordererd by timestamps), but unfortunately it consists of sequence blocks like so:

```
....
2014-10-07T11:07:22.735Z, 1.5250000000000000E+03
2014-10-07T11:07:22.735Z, 1.5250000000000000E+03
2014-10-07T11:07:22.735Z, 1.5250000000000000E+03
2014-10-07T11:07:22.735Z, 1.5250000000000000E+03
2014-10-07T11:07:22.735Z, 1.5250000000000000E+03
2014-10-07T11:07:22.735Z, 1.5250000000000000E+03
```

I would like to average across these duplicate timestamps and replace them on the list with just one pair like so:

```
...
2014-10-07T11:07:22.735Z, <the_mean_value_across_duplicate_timestamps>
```

where, in this case, the `<the_mean_value_across_duplicate_timestamps>` simply is `1.5250000000000000E+03`

What would be the most efficient way to achieve this via python3 and numpy? Indeed, I can write a `for` loop, but I presume this is not the most efficient way of doing thngs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you want, do you want this?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[  1, 1],[  1, 1],[  1, 1],
   [  2, 2],
   [  3, 3], [  3, 3], [  3, 3], [  3, 3],
   [  4, 4], [  4, 4]])
n = np.unique(a[:,0])
print(np.array([   [i, np.mean(a[a[:,0]==i,1])] for i in n]))
```

Comment: wow @CYC that actually does give me the correct result. Can you please explain your last `print` statement if you do not mind?

Comment: Just to show the result, for you to check whether you want or not

Answer (score 0):

unforntunately, you did not state the column names, but I would recommend to use pandas. [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). Afterwards calculate the mean of the values from the grouped time stamps.

```
df.groupby(by=['timestamp'], axis=1).mean()
```

Comment: I would appreciate a solution in python3.7 and numpy - I cannot install pandas due to various limitations imposed.